# Number of ways of forming a team, combinatorial question

Tags: combinatorics

I found this problem in a book and am confused how to approach the problem.

What is the number of ways of forming a team consisting of at least $2$ and at most $n-2$ students from $n$ students?

The answer is $2^n - 2n - 2 $.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $2^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=?+\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can form $2^n$ teams. But one of them will have zero members and $n$ will have 1 members.

Similarly there will be $n$ with $n-1$ members (there are $n$ ways of leaving a person out)
and one team with all the members.

So the answer is 
$$
2^n -1 - n - n - 1 = 2^n -2n -2
$$

OP asked how I get $2^n$. Here is the reasoning:

There is 1 team with no members

There are $\binom{n}{1}=n$ teams with 1 member.

There are $\binom{n}{2}$ teams with 2 members etc.

So the total possible teams is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}
$$

Now you know that
$$
(x+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k
$$
Put $x=1$ to get $2^n$

Comment: Sir how do u get 2^n? Is it just nC0 + nC1 + ....?

Comment: see my edit in the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are $2^n$ ways to choose a team of students of any size, including $0$.  You want to disallow sizes $0$ ( of which there is one ), $1$ ( of which there are $n$ ), $n-1$ ( of which there are $n$ ), and $n$ ( of which there is one )

Comment: Sir, my only question is how do u get 2^n

Comment: @user34304 For each of `n` people, you're choosing one of two things (is said person on the team or not), so there are 2*2*2...*2 = 2^n total possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: find all the ways to make a team of $k$ students from $n$ students, where $k = 1,2,\ldots,n$, then sum all those ways (this will sum to $2^n$), and subtract the special cases for $k=1$, $k=n$, and $k=n-1$.